# Pyserial: readline() is blocking, although timeout is defined

Tags: python, readline, pyserial, blocked

I have an issue with readline() from pyserial.
My code is:

```
import serial

uart = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, timeout=3)

data = uart.readline().decode()
print(data)
uart.close()
```

I'm receiving data from a microcontroller. The problem is, if no data is send from the mc, the program is waiting "forever", although I defined a timeout of 3 seconds.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I have discovered the solution

The problem is, that the Raspberry Pi 3 and 4 uses the "miniUART" as the primary UART and the Raspberry Pi 1 and 2 uses the "PL011".
You can the details here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

To get the timeout break working, you have to change the "PL011" to UART0. By default UART0 (GPIO 14 and 15) is set to "miniUART" and "PL011" is used for the bluetooth modem.

You have to edit the `/boot/config.txt` and add `dtoverlay=disable-bt`.
You also have to disable the system service, that initialises the modem, so it does not connect to the UART, using `sudo systemctl disable hciuart`.

I have done that and now the program waits the timeout for a message and goes on, if no message is received.

Comment: I didn't want to believe that this was my problem, but it was. Great catch.

Answer (score 0):

timeout will only affect the maximum time that  readline() will wait

> timeout = x: set timeout to x seconds (float allowed) returns immediately when the requested number of bytes are available, otherwise wait until the timeout expires and return all bytes that were received until then

try this  :

```
import serial
uart = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, timeout=3)
while True:
   data = uart.readline().decode()
   print(data)
   if not data :
      break
uart.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I have tried your code, but the result is the same. readline() waits longer, than the set timeout(in this case 3 seconds)

Comment: can you try realines instead of readline ?

Comment: readlines() is the same, but I made another discovery. 
I use a Raspberry Pi 3 to run the python code. 
I tested the same code on Raspberry Pi 2, and all works as intended. (Version of Python3 and Pyserial are the same)
I know, that Pi2 and 3 uses different UART's, as you can read here:https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md
So I guess the problem is not my code, but rather a problem with pyserial itself or my hardware.
Thanks for your help.